# GCD in OCaml ( beginner )

Tags: ocaml, greatest-common-divisor

I want to write this simple code :

```
let rec gcd a b =
        if b = 0 then a else gcd b (a mod b);;
val gcd : int -> int -> int = <fun>

Printf.printf "%d da \n" gcd 55 200 ;;
```

This is the code , the error I get is :

```
File "tst.ml", line 3, characters 0-3:
Error: Syntax error
```

And also , can anyone explain to me what is that " int -> int -> int =  " all about ? I know that it must be something about the parameters and the returned value of the function but what and how ? :)

Answer (score 4):

You're passing `gcd` `55` and `200` as separate parameters of `printf`. So, try this:

```
Printf.printf "%d da\n" (gcd 55 200);;
```

Comment: But this is a type error not a syntax one. OP's error message is puzzling.

Comment: A construct like `x y z` isn't syntactically incorrect. It says to call `x` as a function with `y` as its parameter, then pass `z` to the result of that. If the types are correct, this is completely OK. So the problem *is* a type problem.

Comment: That's precisely what I was saying. But if you read the original post, the error reported by OCaml is `File "tst.ml", line 3, characters 0-3:
Error: Syntax error` and not `Error: this expression has type (...) but an expression was expected of type (...)`. Hence why I'm puzzled.

Comment: Oh, nevermind: the syntax error probably comes from the `val` line. I thought the listing was taken from an interactive session rather than the actual content of the file.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you did some copy & paste from an ocaml interactive session, since normally we don't mix up function definitions (the 2 first lines), and function declarations (the third line, though in this case it looks more like the answer of the ocaml interpreter when provided with the definition -  because of the `<fun>` part which isn't syntactically correct in a program, but is used by the interpreter to indicate that it figured out that the value is a *fun*ction) in the same scope.

So, you should not include that third line, and you will have to fix the last instruction, as @JeffreyScofield explained.

```
(* gcd function definition *)
let rec gcd a b =
    if b = 0 then a else gcd b (a mod b);;

(* val gcd: int -> int -> int *)

Printf.printf "%d da \n" (gcd 55 200);;
```

Alternatively, the last line could be written:

```
Printf.printf "%d da \n" @@ gcd 55 200;;
```

The function signature you included by mistake indicates that `gcd` takes a sequence of 2 integer parameters, and returns an integer. The notation is said to be in curried form: each parameter passed to a function *A* yields another function *B* expecting the remaining parameters of *A*. Thus you can read that signature several ways:

- As a function taking 2 integers and returning one,

  ```
  val gcd: int -> int -> int
  ```
- As a function taking an integer, and returning an a function, which takes an integer and returns an integer.

  ```
   val gcd: int -> (int -> int)
  ```

Both notations are equivalent (The arrow "operator" is said to be associative on the right), but the second one helps to understand this idea of function return "chaining".

Answer (score 0):

In int -> int -> int:

- The last int is the return value
- The first two ints are the parameters

[Consider reading this](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/basics.html) to understand function types.